# Needs a webpart where it showcases stock price

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for a Webpart for sharepoint online where it showcases the Stock Price of the company and there should be options to change colors of background and need the company logo too on that webpart

Comment: Are you looking for an third-party web part or are you asking for directions of how to develop this web part? Modern UI or Classic?

Comment: I am asking how to develop it and it should be in the modern UI

Comment: question number one is: where are you getting the stock price from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is SPFX WebPart for Stock Price in GitHub, you could directly install and use from here:

[Stock Info Web Part Overview](https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics/wiki/Stock-Info)

Answer (score 0):

This one has pretty much everything you need, including a free trial

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381291?tab=Overview

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) to create a web part, but to get what you want would be a fair share of custom code. You  can use REST (or whatever you want) to pull in data to the web part. Use a template to display the data you want and apply the css look you need as well. I know this a "1000 ft" answer, but hope it get's you started.